# StreamProvider - RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am building my first app. After many only tutorials and googling I have a home_screen.dart that has a StreamProvider. This then loads a widget from word_list.dart which in the build of the widget calls

```
final MyWords = Provider.of<List<MyWord>>(context) ?? [];
```

The issue I am having is that straight after setting the MyWords I then want to access the information but I think the data isn't loaded. I am accessing the information by using:

```
var fullist = new List(); 
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      fullist.add(i.toString() +
          "^" +
          MyWords[i].question +
          "^" +
          i.toString() +
          "Q^" +
          MyWords[i].docID );
    }
```

I get a very quick error on screen which disappears and then when I check the logs I see:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following RangeError was thrown building MatcherWordList(dirty, dependencies:
[_InheritedProviderScope<List<MyWord>>], state: _MatcherWordListState#64138):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
```

As I say, I am new to this but I think this is because I am accessing the MyWords before it has filled with data... and I need to do some sort of async call for this but can not figure out how it is meant to be done.

Answer (score 0):

The Code is breaking at the moment where you want you to access the MyWords before it has some data. Hence just check for length of your array list to be 5.

```
var fullist = new List(); 
   
   MyForms.length > 4 ?
  
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      fullist.add(i.toString() +
          "^" +
          MyWords[i].question +
          "^" +
          i.toString() +
          "Q^" +
          MyWords[i].docID );
    }
    
    : print("List does not have 5 elements")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but this doesn't really work. It stops the error but then nothing loads to the screen. I have had to rework my code for now and just use a FutureBuilder. This isn't as good but the data being loaded shouldn't really change whilst the user is in this screen so it should work for now.